# Enumeration problem where we have two consecutive events happening

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Two experiments are to be performed. The first can result in any one of $m$ possible outcomes. If the first experiment results in outcome $i$, then the second experiment can result in any of $n_i$ possible outcomes, $i = 1, 2, \ldots , m$. What is the number of possible outcomes of the two experiments?

How do I solve this? I have the impression that I must draw some kind of tree but I'm not sure. Can somebody help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number of possible outcomes is $$\sum_{i=1}^m n_i$$

Comment: Could you tell me your reasoning pls ?

Comment: As you say, think of a tree with $m$ branches and $n_i$ leaves in each branch. The outcomes are exactly the leaves. How many are there? Take $m=2$ , $n_1=4$ and $n_2=6$ for example (examples help in such problems sometimes).

Comment: Ok, but I don't understand why you put n1 = 4 and n2 = 6. Could you explain this pls ? (Why did you put them equal to 4 and 6)

Comment: This is an example....( do you see this "... for example" at the end of the sentence?) Choose any numbers you want.

Comment: Ok, look, here is a drawing that I did. http://imgur.com/wVQ0PWF Is there anything missing from it ?

Comment: Yes, the leaves are missing (are not clear to be more precise).

Comment: Ok, so if I want to generalize the leaves, I should set some random variable like x,y, etc. for  n1, n2, etc. ?

Comment: Yes, exactly...